# using websockets in Hangouts on google+ extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-hangouts

As the title says, I'm working on a google hangout extension and I want to use websockets. Here is some code, which I think should work....

```
if ('WebSocket' in window){
    /* WebSocket is supported.*/
    connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');
    connection.onopen = function () { 
        control_open = true ;
        console.log("websocket"); 
    };  
} else {
    /*WebSockets are not supported.*/

    alert("no web sockets.");
}
```

I never see any output 'websocket' in the logs. When I try to send info, like below, I get a message that the send option doesn't work.

```
connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

BTW, I seem to be able to use only chrome, not FF. I don't know why that is. I'm not concerned as long as one of them seems to work. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: is your localhost a valid websocket server? The `onopen` function will only fire once the websocket connection is successfully established with the server. Try `ws://echo.websocket.org/` as the URL and see if it fires.

Comment: well the ws://echo.websocket.org/ worked. I don't know what to do now. I will post another question.